# Can't make Apache Airflow installation to work

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to run `airflow standalone` but im getting `AirflowConfigException( airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Cannot use relative path: sqlite:///C:\Users\admin/airflow/airflow.db to connect to sqlite. Please use absolute path such as sqlite:////tmp/airflow.db`

I've tried to use `set AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow` but it doesn't seem to work. Airflow is installed in a venv if that makes any difference.

I'm in Win11, python 3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Airflow on Windows is not yet supported unless you use something like WSL.  See [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/prerequisites.html?highlight=windows) and [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10388).

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting the AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable to "C:/airflow" or any other ABSOLUTE PATH (rather than a relative path like "/airflow"). I am speaking in context of Windows